# How to import modules installed under Anaconda3 directory without "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cmd, anaconda

I have both Anaconda and Python3 installed in my Windows OS.
The problem is when I use "pip install module_name" command on the terminal opened from Anaconda Navigator, the module is installed in the following directory:

> C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages

It wouldn't raise any problem when I import the module in Jupyter Notebook,

BUT, it always failed when I try to use the same module from Windows command prompt which says:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'XXX'

Now, even I try to pip install the module again on Windows command prompt, the module will still be installed under

> "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages",

RATHER THAN something like

> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages"

which it supposed to be.

HERE my question is how can I use the installed module on Python3 command prompt WITHOUT installing the same module twice to two different places.

Comment: You could use `python -m pip install` instead. Thereby you can make sure you have the correct `python.exe`. Also, check if there's a `PYTHONHOME` environment variable, which might also affect other installations in a different path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use "python -m pip install", it did successfully install the module to "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages" this time, but when running "import XXX as x", instead of "ModuleNotFoundError", it returned "ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding".

Comment: As for the PYTHONPATH problem, there was not such an environment variable. So I created one and set the path to "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages". After doing this, the command prompt was able to search module form this path. However, Another error raised: "ImportError: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed....  Original error was: cannot import name 'multiarray' from 'numpy.core' (C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py)"

Comment: It's best to not set the env var if not needed then. Python will use the cwd then, which will work for both your installations. As for the qt import problems, this seems like an installation problem...